# $|f''(x)|\leq1$ then exists an extension $g$ with certain bound on the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I am stucked at the following question. Any hint would be really appreciated.

Let $f\in C^{\infty}\left(-1,1\right)$ be such that $|f''(x)|\leq1$
for any $x\in\left(-1,1\right)$. Is it always possible (for whatever
$f$ is) to find a function $g\in C^{\infty}(-3,3)$ such
that $g\equiv f$ on $(-1,1)$, $g\equiv0$ on $(-3,3)\setminus (-2,2)$
and $|g''(x)|\leq100$ for any $x\in(-3,3)$?

Comment: Better use `f''` for the second derivative.

Comment: @Martin I did that.

Comment: Please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960): what have you tried?

Comment: what if $f''(x)=\sin\left(\frac1{1-x^2}\right)$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the constant function $f(x)=2K$ on $(-1,1)$ does of course have $|f''(x)|=0\le 1$ for any $K$. Let's consider large positive values of $K$.

A corresponding $g$ has to satisfy $g(0)=f(0)=2K$ and $g(2)=0$. Hence, by [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) there is some $x_0\in(0,2)$ such that $g'(x_0)=-K$.

Now since $g\equiv 0$ on $[2,3)$, we have $g'(2.5)=0$. Hence, again by MVT there is a $x_1\in (x_0,2.5)$ such that
$$
g''(x_1) = \frac{K}{2.5-x_0} > \frac{K}{0.5}.
$$
Hence, when $K>200$, you can't find $g$ satisfying the desired properties and $|g''(x)|\le 100$.

The intuition here is that in order for a smooth function to have a large change of value in a small interval, it has to have a large derivative by MVT. Then in order to make a large change of derivative, it has to have a large second derivative.